# Property file based conditional patterns in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, pattern-matching

I have a property file (a.txt) which has the values (Example values given below) like below

```
test1=10  
test2=20  
test33=34  
test34=35
```

By reading this file, I need to produce an output like below

```
value = 35_20_34_10
```

which means => I have a pattern like **test34_test2_test33_test1**

Note, If the 'test33' has any value other than 34 then I need to produce the value like below

```
value = 35_20_10
```

which means => I have a pattern like **test34_test2_test1**

Now my problem is, every time when the customer is making the change in the logic, I am making the change in the code. So what I expect is, I want to keep the logic (pattern) in another property file so I will be sending the two inputs to the **util** (one input is the property file (A.txt) another input will be the 'pattern.txt'),

My util has to be compare the A.txt and the business logic 'pattern.txt' and produce the output like

```
value = 35_20_34_10 (or) 
value = 35_20_10
```

If there an example for such pattern based logic as I expect?
Any predefined util / java class does this?

Any help would be Great.

thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, svasa's answer makes a lot of sense, but covers different level of
>   abstraction. I recommend you read his answer too, that pattern should
>   be useful.

You may wanna look at [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) and [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) libraries to see how they structure their API.

Those are [template engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor)s - they usually have some abstraction of pattern or format, and abstraction of variable/value binding (or namespace, or source). You can render a template by binding it with a binding/namespace, which yields the result.

For example, you may wanna have a pattern `"<a> + <b>"`, and binding that looks like a map: `{a: "1", b: "2"}`. By binding that binding to that pattern you'll get `"1 + 2"`, when interpreting `<...>` as variables.

You basically load the pattern from your *pattern.txt*, then load your data file *A.txt* (for example, by treating it as properties and using [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class) and construct binding based on these properties. You'll get your output and possibility to customize the pattern all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You may call the sequences like `test34_test2_test33_test1` as a pattern, let me call them as constraints when building something.

To me this problem best fits into a 
[builder pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/1425/builder-design-pattern-in-java).

When building the value you want, you tell the builder that these are my constraints(pattern) and these are my original properties like below:

```
new MyPropertiesBuilder().setConstraints(constraints).setProperties(original).buildValue();
```

**Details:**

Set some constraints in a separate file where you specify the order of the properties and their values like :

```
test34=desiredvalue-could-be-empty
test2=desiredvalue-could-be-empty
test33=34
test1=desiredvalue-could-be-empty
```

The builder goes over the constraints in the order specified, but get the values from the original properties and build the desired string.

One way to achieve your requirement through builder pattern is to define classes like below :

**Interface:**

```
public interface IMyPropertiesBuilder
{
    public void setConstraints( Properties properties );

    public void setProperties( Properties properties );

    public String buildValue();
}
```

**Builder**

```
public class MyPropertiesBuilder implements IMyPropertiesBuilder
{
    private Properties constraints;

    private Properties original;


    @Override
    public void setConstraints( Properties constraints )
    {
        this.constraints = constraints;
    }

    @Override
    public String buildValue()
    {
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

        Iterator it = constraints.keySet().iterator();

        while ( it.hasNext() )
        {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            if ( original.containsKey( key ) && constraints.getProperty( key ) != null && original.getProperty( key ).equals( constraints.getProperty(  key ) ) )
            {
                value.append( original.getProperty( key ) );
                value.append( "_" );
            }
        }

        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperties( Properties properties ) 
    {
        this.original = properties;
    }


}
```

**User**

```
public class MyPropertiesBuilderUser
{

   private Properties original = new Properties().load(new FileInputStream("original.properties"));;

   private Properties constraints = new Properties().load(new FileInputStream("constraints.properties"));

   public String getValue()
   {

     String value = new MyPropertiesBuilder().setConstraints(constraints).setProperties(original).buildValue();
    }
}
```